# Using sed, how can I replace all occurences of X with Y, but only after seeing Z?

Tags: regex, replace, sed

I am trying to replace all spaces with pipe (|), but only after seing the two double quotes.

Input:

```
02/15/2014 00:00:35 CST 1400130035 192.168.39.60 [15/Feb/2015:04:05:10 +0000] 331184 "POST /Test?param=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 '-' 450/-/351 - - - 34322155 TEST -
```

Output:

```
02/15/2014 00:00:35 CST 1400130035 192.168.39.60 [15/Feb/2015:04:05:10 +0000] 331184 "POST /Test?param=1 HTTP/1.1"|200|'-'|450/-/351|-|-|-|34322155|TEST|-
```

Thx

Comment: Why do you specifically need to use `sed`?

Comment: `sed` does not seem to support lookbehind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a test:

```
sed -e :a -e 's/\(.*".*".*\) /\1|/;ta'
```

Using the hold buffer:

```
sed 'h;s/.*".*"//;s/ /|/g;x;s/\(.*".*"\).*/\1/;G;s/\n//'
```

Comment: The only simplification I can see is instead of `.*".*"` using `.*"`, which works the same due to greedy matching. It could be considered better, worse or identical depending on the details of the data.

Comment: @ooga: But that would also match a single double-quote. Come to think of it, my solutions could malfunction if there were more than two double-quotes. Guess I'll have to make them a little more bullet-proof...

Comment: There's no way to make it perfect with regular expressions. Your way would also fail if there were two double-quoted strings before the part where spaces are to be replaced by pipes. As I said, it depends on the details of the data format and how much we feel we can trust it. It'll never be bullet-proof, or to put it another way, if we wanted to make it bullet-proof we wouldn't use sed since it would get too hairy to justify!

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/"/&\n/2;h;y/ /|/;G;s/.*\n(.*)\n(.*)\n.*/\2\1/' file
```

Put a marker following the second `"` and copy the line. Replace all spaces with `|`'s and then append the copied line and reconstitute the line as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Just use awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\""} {gsub(/ /,"|",$3)} 1' file
02/15/2014 00:00:35 CST 1400130035 192.168.39.60 [15/Feb/2015:04:05:10 +0000] 331184 "POST /Test?param=1 HTTP/1.1"|200|'-'|450/-/351|-|-|-|34322155|TEST|-
```